# CUPS Printer works from admin interface, but "Processing - Not Connected?" from client

Tags: printing, ubuntu-16.04, cups

I have a printer installed on a CUPS server (hostname `hightower`).  If I print a test page from the admin interface it works.

The printer appears on an Ubuntu 16.04 client/networked computer, but when I try to print it just hangs.  The printer dialog "Document Print Status" shows

> Processing - Not connected?

On the client, if I go into Job attributes (right click the job > view attributes), I get:

```
job-more-info                http://localhost/jobs/565
job-printer-state-message    Unable to locate printer "hightower.local"
job-printer-state-reasons    ['connecting-to-device']
job-printer-uri              ipp://localhost/printers/Lexmark_T644
...
job-uri                      ipp://localhost/jobs/565
```

In the CUPS admin interface, under Jobs, it shows:

```
▲ ID ▲           Name       User        Size    Pages       State
Lexmark_T644-1   Unknown    Withheld    1k      Unknown     completed at
    Mon 03 Apr 2017 10:44:04 PM PDT
```

Answer (score 0):

That printer is disabled. Please run:

```
cupsenable Lexmark_T644-1
```

or if you prefer doing it in browser:

```
http://localhost:631
```

Printers/Lexmark_T644-1/Maintenance/Resume printer